# Meteor - Display single memo page from memos list

Tags: javascript, meteor

Im pulling my hair out right now.
Cant get to display single memo detailed page for my memos app. I tried tens of solutions. Sometimes i can see data for a milisecond then it dissapears. 
I did route in Iron Router

```
// router.js 

    this.route('memo',{
       path: '/memo/:_id', 
        data: function() { return Memos.findOne({id: this.params._id}); }
    });
```

I wrote helper ( not sure why if iron router handles this, right ? )

```
    //helpers.js

    Template.memo.helpers({
        memo: function(){ return Memos.findOne({id: this._id})}
    });

Template.memos.events({
    'click #remove-memo': function(event,template){
       console.log('memo removed : ' + this._id);
        Memos.remove(this._id);
    },
    **'click #li-body': function(event, template){
        console.log('entering li body : ' + this._id + ' title: ' + this.title);
        Router.go('/memo/'+this._id);
    }**
});
```

Template for the whole list

```
    //memos.html
   <template name="memos"> 
        <ul>
            {{#each memos}}
            <li class="notes-main">
                <span id="remove-memo" class="ex icon-close"></span>
                <a class="no-decoration" **href="{{pathFor 'memo' }}**">
                <span id="li-body" class="no-decoration">
                    <span class="notes-title">{{this.title}}</span>
                    <span class="notes-author">{{author}}</span>
                    <span class="notes-body-prev">{{body}}</span>
                </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
  </template>
```

Then single memo template

```
//memo.html

<template name="memo">
    title : {{title}}
    <br>
    body: {{body}}

</template>
```

Cant get this to work. What am I missing here ?
Console shows : `"entering li body : zj9y3y3mNvQ6uK7Eg title: zxxxxxxxxxx" "**NaN**zxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"` So it seems to retrive correct data but it doesnt get rendered (?) , also Ive no ide wht 'NaN' is doing in front of all messages bodies.
Any help on how to get single memo displayed, much appreciated.

Comment: You have an `each memos` in your html but I don't see a `memos` helper. Is that in your code?

Comment: Yes, memos helper works just fine. I can see list of all memos, the problem is single detailed memo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo:

```
Memos.findOne({id: this.params._id});
```

should be

```
Memos.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
```

or just

```
Memos.findOne(this.params._id);
```

Comment: Memos.findOne(this.params._id) solved the problem. I guess sometimes we need fresh look of someone else. Thanks