# Text flashes and disappear

Tags: meteor

This question will be similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925697/meteor-display-single-memo-page-from-memos-list) I asked earlier. I got it working, copied solution, but there must be something Im missing here. I start with the code:

router.js:

```
this.route('note',{
    path: '/note/:_id',
    data: function() { return Notes.findOne(this.params._id); },  
});
this.route('notes', {
    waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('notes')}
});
```

template 'notes' :

```
<table id="notes-table">
    {{#each notes}}
        <tr id="table-row">
            <td id="indicator"></td>
            <td id="remove-note" class="icon-close notes-table-class"></td>
            <td id="notes-title" class="Nbody notes-table-class">{{this.title}}</td>
            <td id="notes-body-prev" class="Nbody notes-table-class">{{this.body}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
</table>
```

helpers.js :

```
Template.notes.events({
    'click .Nbody': function(events,template){
        console.log('displaying note : ' + this._id);
        Router.go('/note/'+this._id);
    }
});
```

Template 'note' is simple {{title}} and {{body}}

The problem is, when I click on the note table body it does take me where it should be, which is single note, but its text just flashes for a second and disappear immediately and never comes back, so I see nothing..
Question: What is the problem?

I do not get any error in the console.

The Differences between this and 'memo' solutions are:
- here im using table instead of span's
- I dropped wrapping clickable body in 's tags ( I think this might be the reason )

Comment: Have you removed autopublish ? If this is the case, where do you subscribe to the Notes collection ?

Comment: Autopublish, inseecure all removed. I updated my post so you can see where do I subscribe. This got me thinking, and when I moved waitOn to Router.configure it started working. If you wouldnt mind writing constructive answer to help others, and also so I can rate it, that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to subscribe in 'note' route to be able to retrieve it:

client:

```
this.route('note',{
    path: '/note/:_id',
    waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('note',this.params._id )}
    data: function() { return Notes.findOne(this.params._id); },  
});
this.route('notes', {
    waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('notes')}
});
```

server:

```
Meteor.publish('note', function(noteId){
    return Notes.find(this.params._id);
})
```

In comment you wrote that it started to work when you : `moved waitOn to Router.configure`. Route.configure waitOn is working for all routes and because `Method.publish('notes')` function probably returns `Notes.find()` then `note` starts to work correct.